# Regex - Skip subsequent matches (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to delimit the following into a table, but am running into issues with the name having 2 spaces in it or else "[\s]{2,}" would work.  I also can't ignore whitespace between letters since the 1st column ends with a letter and the 2nd column starts with a letter.

I would like to skip any whitespace in between letters after the 1st occurrence.

String:

```
> TESTID  DR5 777777 0    50000        TEST  NAME    23.40     600000.00   1000000 20 5   09 05 18  09 07 18   3876.00
```

- TESTID
- DR5 777777 0
- 50000
- TEST NAME
- 23.40
- 600000.00
- 1000000 20 5
- 09 05 18
- 09 07 18
- 3876.00

Answer (score -1):

I will try to solve your stated problem (vs the regex thing), because I don't fully understand the regex question.

If I were going to make that string into a list, I would do it like this:

```
my_str = "TESTID  DR5 777777 0    50000        TEST  NAME    23.40     600000.00   1000000 20 5   09 05 18  09 07 18   3876.00"

my_list = [section for section in my_str.split(" ") if section != ""]
```

This uses list comprehension to filter out the blank strings from the split.

You can also use a regular expression as the separator.

```
import re

my_str = "TESTID  DR5 777777 0    50000        TEST  NAME    23.40     600000.00   1000000 20 5   09 05 18  09 07 18   3876.00"

my_list = re.split(r'\s{2, }', my_str)
```

Comment: my problem still stands using that method.  The regex "[\s]{2,}" would still split 'TEST' and 'NAME' which should be grouped together

Comment: That's because TEST and NAME are separated by two spaces. If you don't NEED those two spaces, try `my_str.replace("TEST  NAME", "TEST NAME")` first.

Comment: "TEST  NAME" was just an example.  There could be any combination of names with 2 spaces between.  So i can't just replace that exact name.